# return message if input is in array

Tags: php

I have a form validation that, so far, returns an error message if either of two defined words/phrase are present in the input area:

```
add_filter('gform_validation_3', 'custom_validation');
function custom_validation($validation_result){
    $form = $validation_result["form"];
    foreach($form['fields'] as &$field){
        /* Check that the value of the field that was submitted. e.g. the name="input_1" that is generated by Gravity Forms */
        if($_POST['input_4'] == "Your First Name" || "SEO"){
         // set the form validation to false
         $validation_result["is_valid"] = false;
            //The field ID can be found by hovering over the field in the backend of WordPress
             if($field["id"] == "4"){
                 $field["failed_validation"] = true;
                 $field["validation_message"] = "This field needs to be your actual first name.";
             }
         }
        }
    //Assign modified $form object back to the validation result
    $validation_result["form"] = $form;
    return $validation_result;
}
```

I'm not sure now how to create an array to define the words that are not allowed, so that I can have a much longer list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the first "if" is incorrect, I think you meant:

```
if($_POST['input_4'] == "Your First Name" || $_POST['input_4'] =="SEO")
```

A good way to achieve what you long is:

```
$forbidden_words = ["Your First Name", "SEO"];
$is_valid = !in_array($_POST['input_4'], $forbidden_words); //false if the word is in array
```

After that you may go:

```
if($is_valid)
     //do magic
```

Comment: Thanks, that is better. I updated the code, and it does reject submissions that are equal to either of the two variables. However, If the textarea contains other acceptable words in addition to the banned words, it validates. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: oh, so you want to evaluate if it contains banned words, not if the text is equal to banned words? I think that would indeed need recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
<?php

$blacklisted = ['some', 'ugly', 'bad', 'words'];

if(in_array('ugly', $blacklisted)){
  echo('bad word spotted');
}
```

demo: https://repl.it/@kallefrombosnia/DarkvioletDeepPolygons

Comment: yes, thank you! i just found the answer, but will leave this up in case it is helpful to anyone else.